# How to create Backup and Restore in Meteor.js on Windows

Tags: meteor, backup, restore

I would like to create a backup and restore in Meteor.js on Windows.
On other platform like Mac and Linux we can `hitchcott:app-dump` package.
But On Windows isn't support.

So what should we do on Windows. Is There a package for backup and restore on Windows.

Comment: Be careful! You first ask how to store and retrieve data on Windows, but then you ask for a library. Question asking us to find a book, tool, software, library, giraffe are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I mean that I want create backup and restore page in meteor.js and I develop the meteor app on windows and there is a package name `hitchcott:app-dump` but it is not support on windows. I want to know are there any packages for do this, or are there any solution for do this.